# Cyclical Loop Between OneHotEncoder and KNNImpute in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I'm working with a really simple dataset. It has some missing values, both in categorical and numeric features. Because of this, I'm trying to use sklearn.preprocessing.KNNImpute to get the most accurate imputation I can. However, when I run the following code:

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=120)

imputer.fit_transform(x_train)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Private'`

That makes sense, it obviously can't handle categorical data. But when I try to run OneHotEncoder with:

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop="first")

encoder.fit_transform(x_train[categorical_features])
```

It throws the error: `ValueError: Input contains NaN`

I'd prefer to use `KNNImpute` even with the categorical data as I feel like I'd be losing some accuracy if I just use a `ColumnTransform` and impute with numeric and categorical data seperately. Is there any way to get `OneHotEncoder` to ignore these missing values? If not, is using `ColumnTransform` or a simpler imputer a better way of tackling this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `KNNImpute` to fill one-hot-encoded categoricals will generally produce values between 0 and 1 (unless `n_neighbors=1`); is that fine for your use?  And if so, how would you want to encode missing values: as a new column, or as all-zeros?

Comment: @BenReiniger That should be fine as long as I just round the value between 0 and 1, right? For the second part of your question, I think defaulting to 0s for missing categorical variables would be the best. However, I was hoping there was a way to ignore these NAs in `OneHotEncoder()` so I could KNNImpute those NAs in categorical variables as well. Is there no real way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are open issues/PRs to handle missing values on `OneHotEncoder`, but it's not clear yet what the options would be.  In the interim, here's a manual approach.

- Fill categorical missings with pandas or `SimpleImputer` with the string "missing".
- Use `OneHotEncoder` then.
- Use the one-hot encoder's `get_feature_names` to identify the columns corresponding to each original feature, and in particular the "missing" indicator.
- For each row and each original categorical feature, when the 1 is in the "missing" column, replace the 0's with `np.nan`; then delete the missing indicator column.
- Now everything should be set up to run `KNNImputer`.
- Finally, if desired, postprocess the imputed categorical-encoding columns.  (Simply rounding might get you an all-zeros row for a categorical feature, but I don't think with `KNNImputer` you could get more than one 1 in a row.  You could argmax instead to get back exactly one 1.)

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped out a ton appreciate it

Comment: Can we use `strategy="most_frequent"` for `SimpleImputer`, instead of replace it with "missing" string? But It will return an array, without a column name which lead to problem for `OneHotEncoder`.

Comment: @xkderhaka That won't do what the Question asks for; you won't be able to distinguish between the missing values and the most frequent values, and the `KNNImputer` won't be able to do anything for the categorical features' missing values.

Comment: I mean, what I am understand, if we use `strategy=most_frequent`, it will replace the `NaN` with the most frequent data to the NaN, right? After that, there's no more `NaN` anymore in the dataframe (as it replace by most frequent). If there is no more NaN, we can continue doing OHE, aren't we?