# One Hot Encoding preserve the NAs for imputation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan, missing-data, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use KNN for imputing categorical variables in python.

In order to do so, a typical way is to one hot encode the variables before. However sklearn OneHotEncoder() doesn't handle NAs so you need to rename them to something which creates a seperate variable.

Small reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

#Create random pandas with categories to impute
data0 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["1","2"],data = [["A",np.nan],["B","A"],[np.nan,"A"],["A","B"]])
```

original data frame:

```
data0
     1    2
0    A  NaN
1    B    A
2  NaN    A
3    A    B
```

Proceed with one hot encoding:

```
#Rename for sklearn OHE
enc_missing = SimpleImputer(strategy="constant",fill_value="missing")
data1 = enc_missing.fit_transform(data0)
# Perform OHE:
OHE = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
data_OHE = OHE.fit_transform(data1)
```

Data_OHE is now one hot encoded:

```
Data_OHE
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

But because of the seperate "missing" category - i dont have any nans to impute anymore.

**My desired output of one hot encoding**

```
array([[1,        0,      np.nan, np.nan],
       [0,        1,        1,       0   ],
       [np.nan, np.nan,     1,       0   ], 
       [1,        0,        0,       1   ]
       ])
```

Such that I keep nans for later imputation.

Do you know any way to do this?

From my understanding this is something that has been discussed in the scikit-learn Github repo [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12025)
and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11996#issuecomment-512757230), i.e. to make OneHotEncoder handle this automatically with a `handle_missing` argument, but i am unsure of the status of their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling of missing values in `OneHotEncoder` ended up getting merged in [PR17317](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/17317), but it operates by just treating the missing values as a new category (no option for other treatments, if I understand correctly).

One manual approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923804/10495893).  The first step isn't strictly necessary now because of the above PR, but maybe filling with custom text will make it easier to find the column?

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for! - hope to see this directly implemented in OneHotEncoder someday..

Comment: Hi again Ben. I am able to perform the steps provided in your answer to make the one hot encoding. But how would you go about putting this into a sklearn pipeline? If I create my own MyOneHotEncoder class using `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` it cannot fit to test data due to: "Incompatible dimension between the fitted dataset and the one to be transformed". I suspect this is because the sklearn OneHotEncoder is now wrapped in my own class and thus the `"handle_unknown = ignore"` is not playing out its role anymore. Might be suitable for a new post instead of comment here.. 
Kr
Kasper

Comment: I didn't pursue writing a custom estimator because it doesn't seem very easy and fairly niche.  But if you've started, I (and others here probably) would be happy to answer specific new questions.

Comment: But is it niche? I mean, I see many people who wants to impute a categorical variable using KNN (or some other method that requires OHE) and it seems this is the only way? Am I completely missing an alternative way to use KNN on categorical variables?. The pipeline setup is more because that's my go-to in order to ensure we don't have information leak between train/test when evaluating the model performance. Might post another question on my problems on how to fit this custom function into a pipeline.

Comment: I've setup a new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635031/implement-custom-one-hot-encoding-function-for-sklearn-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(),
    SimpleImputer(),
    Ridge()
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```